# Not able to install c++ eclipse indigo after completely uninstalling from ubuntu 11.10

Tags: c++, eclipse, installation, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-11.10

I had installed Indigo eclipse successfully earlier in Ubuntu (Virtual Machine) with following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt
```

However, it got messed up when I did an update from its "Install New Software" tab. After running following commands, I removed eclipse completely.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge eclipse
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/eclipse /usr/lib/eclipse/ /usr/share/eclipse /usr/share/man/man1/eclipse.1.gz /etc/eclipse.ini
```

However, now I want to again install eclipse in my Ubuntu. When I run the above commands, it simply doesn't go well and stop at following execution:

```
milind@milind-VirtualUbuntuOneiric:~$ sudo apt-get install eclipse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  eclipse
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 147 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/17.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 131 kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  eclipse
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Selecting previously deselected package eclipse.
(Reading database ... 133931 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking eclipse (from .../eclipse_3.7.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Setting up eclipse (3.7.0-0ubuntu1) ...
milind@milind-VirtualUbuntuOneiric:~$
```

Trying for so long (with restarting the VBox many times), but no luck. Can you please help me with:

1. How to install eclipse for C++ (I think indigo) from command line
   like earlier I did ?
2. If command line is not working then what is the latest C++ eclipse site to get it ?
3. How to install proper CDT for this eclipse so that it can be used
   nicely for debugging (which was my root problem) ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a few problems installing from apt recently (Ubuntu 11.10). I eventually ended up downloading a build from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and then installing to a custom location [/home/usrname/programs/eclipse]. This was the only way I could get the marketplace to work.